# IOS - Accessing Audio Stream from Ipod, Pausing and Changing Volume

Tags: ios, audio, ipod, volume

I am working on an app that needs to pause and unpause the audio stream coming from the ipod app. Is there any way to do that? I want to make a button that once you press it, it pauses the currently playing song on the ipod app. Pressing it again unpauses where the music left off. I am also working on a way to change the volume of the ipod app, is there anyway to do this that does not rely on the user manually moving a slider?

Any help at all would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple will not be happy about you changing the sound level without the user knowing about it or even doing it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this framework if you want: [Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)
Specially the [MPMusicPlayerController Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

You have this:

```
Controlling Playback
– play
– pause
– stop
Managing Playback Mode and State
  volume ( property )
```